# How to create a single commit with the differences between the local and remote Git repositories?

Tags: git, push, commit, squash

In Git, let's say I've been working on a local branch:

```
  Common ancestor      
        /\
       A  \
      /    X
     B      \
    /        Y
   C       remote
 local
```

I made local commits A, B and C and in the mean time the remote branch moved on with commits X and Y. So I do a pull and get:

```
  Common ancestor      
        /\
       A  \
      /    X
     B      \
    /        Y
   C        /remote
    \      /
     \    /
      \  /
       \/
       M
     local
```

If I now push, the remote history will include all my A, B, C and M commits... but this isn't what I want.

I want to just push a single commit with the differences from my local branch so the remote branch will just look like this with none of the merging complexity:

```
  Common ancestor      
         \
          \
           X
            \
             Y
              \
               N
             remote
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a

```
git pull --rebase
```

Which is equivalent to `git fetch` and a `git rebase` instead of a `git merge`.

Answer (score 1):

Just merge the local changes into the remove ones to get the *N* commit:

1. Create, checout a branch *`remote_n`* locally, and pull all data from remote's master into the *remote_n* branch:

   ```
   git branch remote_n
   git checkout remote_n
   git pull origin master
   ```
2. Do a merge of master's HEAD into *`remote_n`*, fix inconsisences, and commit changes, so you will get the single *N* commit (by using [`--squash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517785/github-merge-many-commits-into-one) option):

   ```
   git merge --squash master
   vim ...
   git add .
   git commit
   ```
3. Push the result *N* commit into remote's master branch:

   ```
   git push remote master
   ```

**NOTE:** You will get the local *`remote_n`* branch as a new *master* branch for your repo.

If you really need to avoid the merge do manually something like:

1. Get diff of *Common*, and *C* commits:

   ```
   git diff Common_sha C_sha > common_c.diff
   ```
2. Reset tree down to *Common* commit, pull remote changes, apply the diff, and commit it:

   ```
   git reset --hard Common_sha
   git pull remote master
   git apply --ignore-space-change common_c.diff
   git commit
   ```
3. Push the result *N* commit into remote's master branch:

   ```
   git push remote master
   ```

**NOTE:** this model don't take into account *binary* files that can't be displayed by `git diff`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not quite sure this would work... `git merge master` brings commits A, B and C into the history so wouldn't they be pushed in addition to the *N* commit?

Comment: @SteveChambers so you need to avoid that commits?

Comment: Yes - let's put it another way: I want to make it look as if I've only just pulled the remote branch and made some changes without anyone else changing anything in the mean time - so there's a single line of history. I could obviously do this by pulling the remote into a new local branch and quickly reapplying my changes manually but am wondering if there's a simpler/better way.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but unfortunately this gave "error: patch failed" with further messages on individual files such as "patch failed", "patch does not apply" and warnings such as "<blah> has type 100644, expected 100755".

Comment: @SteveChambers on which files?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46006/discussion-between-steve-chambers-and-majioa)